# xming in bash - copy text

Tags: bash, linux-device-driver, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x11-forwarding, xming

When I open my python IDE from Ubuntu using xming over bash on Windows 10

I can copy text from windows or the bash terminal and paste into the IDE but I am unable to copy text from the IDE (displaying using the xming driver) and paste it into bash or windows.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks Microsoft and @Richturner for your help in continuing to improve linux capabilities within windows

Comment: Try this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/04/13/copy-and-paste-arrives-for-linuxwsl-consoles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Biswapriyo noted, Microsoft has rolled out a fix for this issue. Thanks @Microsoft